# ADFS SSO - Multiple claims aware application able to redirect to one another

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs

I have an ADFS server authenticating two sites - SiteA and SiteB , both sites working fine when accessed from the browser , but when I try to access SiteB from SiteA or vice versa , 
I get the following error "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

Digging deeper I found that , upon redirect from A->B , SiteA FedAuth cookies are used by SiteB as well, therefore the decryption is not done properly .

My doubts
1)Is my above understanding correct?
2)If so is there any way to redirect without sending the cookie (Site a ,Site b made on ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you see this error?

What does the ADFS event log say?

Are you doing any cryptographic operation?

These cookies are used to provide SSO to ADFS across both applications - so when you login to A and then access B from the browser, you don't have to login again.

Comment: Okay i found the issue was because of invalid certifcate on sites